# Importing a wallet file

Tags: wallets

Need help restoring my account. Briefly:

1. I had to delete my geth folder as it was getting to 400gb.
2. I DO HAVE a my original keystore folder and password.
3. I upgraded to MIST v10 which syncs to 99% & 72 blocks then stops.
4. If I try to import my account by drag & drop my keystore file it says
   importing but nothing happens.
5. I'm also trying to use my keystore file name to access my ethereum via Exodus but just getting error messages. I'm not sure how much of the keystore info I should be using - all incl UTC-2017 etc or just the last 40 or so letters/numbers after the last - ???

Suggestions please.

Thanks in  advance

Comment: Firstly, please format your question. We are not ready to read bytecode.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what you are asking?

Comment: Yet you formatted :)